# Why is my reputation reverted to the one I had on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support

I was using Stack Overflow as usual, until 5 minutes ago, and all of a sudden when I clicked on my profile, it showed the page isn't available and that I can join this community. When I selected join this community, I logged in again, but my reputation got down to 101. This was 328 or something before that. Why is this happening? All my badges are gone. But my questions are still here.

Also, my username was "coder dude twodee", now it just says "user30863". How do I get back to my original account?

My Cryptography Stack Exchange site reputation was 101, but Stack Overflow was around 328. What is happening? My earlier profile shows "user5831063".

Comment: Looks like you account has been deleted..

Comment: But why is it deleted?

Comment: don't know, may wait for a moderator to respond.

Comment: I've pinged the site mods, but *from a cursory inspection* it *looks like* it was removed as a twin account (possibly with voting irregularities) of another account

Comment: Which account is the other twin?

Comment: Do you have someone at work that has upvoted a few of your questions/answers ?

Comment: @Jaco: It isn't like that. If someone votes the users q/a repetitively, it will be counted as serial votes and just be reversed. No one will be penalized. Voting Irregularities is when two accounts, from the same IP, are continuously voting each other, in a proper pattern. Moderators have tools to view when a user was logged in and logged out, what IP addresses are they from, have they always been voting each others answers, etc. It becomes clear that when two users, never logged in at the same time, from the same IP and voting each others posts are doing Voting irregularities.

Comment: This is why moderators should reach out to people before performing draconian actions like this.

Comment: @Jaco, to continue, Voting irregularities lead to both the accounts deleted if they have made no contributions to the site. Normally the twin account (or sockpuppet) never has made contributions, and is delete. The other account, if has made contributions is temporarily suspended and all the unfair votes reversed.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet to be fair, the "draconian" actions are usually for spam accounts where reaching out would be a complete waste of time.  It's unusual for legitimate accounts to be affected.

Comment: You should have received an email on your registered email address, if you've been suspended for voting irregularities (mostly if your account isn't deleted).

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, if this user's account wasn't a spam one (as the user is saying), the user should have received an email on the registered email address saying that the account has been suspended, and other information.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ: The account has not been suspended. It has been obliterated. (Allegedly)

Comment: @MrLister: I think he just changed the name on this "new"/"old" account to match his desired name from the obliterated one. A bit confusing to have done so while this conversation is still taking place, but yeah.

Comment: Of course this could all just be the fault of CACHING

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, yes it has been obliterated. If you had read my earlier comments, you would've seen that I've mentioned that the account gets deleted if there have been no contributions from it, or all or most its reputation has been gained from the sockpuppet. That must have been the case of this user (if at all there was voting irregularity).

Comment: "obliterated" sounds like it can't simply be undeleted; would the powers that be really be that harsh? And why weren't his posts (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841810/how-to-reposition-div-on-decrease-in-screen-size-with-css)) deleted as well? His [chat account](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5831063/coder-dude-twodee) is still up too.

Comment: @MrLister - [according to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131666/152099), "only negatively-scored posts are deleted" when the account is deleted; but all posts are deleted when an account is destroyed - so that doesn't seem to have happened here. Only the mods will know though, the speculation probably isn't very useful.

Comment: @MrLister, IIRC users can be undeleted and even unmerged (to allow rolling back mistakes), but it's not that easy to do. However, if the deletion was a mistake, I'm sure the mods will do everything to restore the user as they were. If.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ: Great, we're all agreed that it's not a suspension. Then why your comments about getting an email when you're suspended?

Comment: @MrLister: Posts are not deleted when their owning account is deleted. Their rep is reassigned to _Community_, though. This is called post dissociation.

Comment: I deleted your (other) account because there was (more than) enough evidence that it was a sock puppet. If I remember correctly it had contributed to about 90 percent of votes.. I checked location. , login credentials , names and lots of other things before doing that.  I also sent a message about this deletion.

Comment: Another thing. There are processes in place to ensure that mods don't delete accounts inadvertently. Only after careful analysis do we come to a conclusion.  Deleting / destroying  an account is used only as the last resort.

Comment: You gotta be pretty stupid to use a sock puppet account and then complain about the fallout when it gets deleted.

Answer (score 62):

Your account was deleted by a moderator because all indications were that it was a sock puppet of [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3720930/dash). That account was receiving a large amount of targeted votes from your account, and has been suspended and emailed with the reason for the actions taken.

I've reviewed the evidence that we have in the system, and both of these accounts came from the same location, had the same name, had the same birthday, and had matching login credentials. I think the moderator involved made the right call, as I find it extremely hard to believe that these were accounts by two different people.

Are you sure there isn't something else you want to tell us?